# select this and div inside of this

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-animate

i have two divs like this:

```
<div class="square">

    <div class="head">
      <span>material</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

on click on square div i want to animate:

```
$('.square').click(function(){
    $(this), $(this).find('div').animate({
        width: "700px"
    }, 1500);


    });
```

I mean I want to animate both: this and div inside of this. I do not want selection of second div with class or id. I also tried function(){($(this), $(this).find('div').animate
but it's useless.

any suggestions?

Comment: both the head and the square too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add` to combine matches:

```
$('.square').click(function(){
    $(this).add($(this).find('div')).animate({
        width: "700px"
    }, 1500);
});
```

Behind the scenes jQuery objects are just arrays. This will add the matching find result to the `this` element and then apply animate to both.

You can also use `addBack()` to re-include the previous jQuery context (the previous value in the *traversal stack*): http://api.jquery.com/addback/

```
$('.square').click(function(){
    $(this).find('div').addBack().animate({
        width: "700px"
    }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.square').click(function(){

$(this).children('div').animate({
    width: "700px"
}, 1500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to select two different elements and animate them both, try giving all elements that you want animated the same class name, and then `.find()` that and animate.

So, your HTML would be:

```
<div class="square animate-me">

    <div class="head animate-me">
      <span>material</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

and your jQuery would be:

```
$('.square').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.animate-me').animate({
        width: '700px'
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but it doesnt work for me, because there are many many many objects to be animated and on click of each should be animated the one was clicked and div inside it.